# Getting error while starting one of nodemanager for kerberos secure hadoop-2.2.0 cluster

Tags: hadoop, kerberos, hadoop2

I have enabled kerberos security for hadoop 2.2.0 cluster. But while starting nodemanager i am getting below error:
Machine-1 namenode works as datanode at this node nodemanager is running but at machine-2 datanode nodemanager giving below error

```
 2015-05-29 15:06:00,916 DEBUG    org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService: noteFailure org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: Failed to initialize container executor
 2015-05-29 15:06:00,925 INFO  org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService: Service NodeManager failed in       
 state INITED; cause: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: Failed to     initialize container executor   
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: Failed to   initialize container executor  
        at     org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.serviceInit(NodeManager.java:148)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.initAndStartNodeManager(NodeManager.java:338)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.main(NodeManager.java:386)
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/home/hadoopnew/hadoop-2.2.0/bin/container-executor": error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1041)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:407)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:379)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:589)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.LinuxContainerExecutor.init(LinuxContainerExecutor.java:147)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.serviceInit(NodeManager.java:146)
    ... 3 more
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:135)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1022)
    ... 8 more
    2015-05-29 15:06:00,959 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService: Service: NodeManager entered state STOPPED
    2015-05-29 15:06:00,959 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService: NodeManager: stopping services, size=0
    2015-05-29 15:06:00,959 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: refCount=0
    2015-05-29 15:06:00,959 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Redundant shutdown
    java.lang.Throwable
    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl.shutdown(MetricsSystemImpl.java:555)
    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.DefaultMetricsSystem.shutdownInstance(DefaultMetricsSystem.java:72)
    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.DefaultMetricsSystem.shutdown(DefaultMetricsSystem.java:68)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.serviceStop(NodeManager.java:208)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.stop(AbstractService.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stop(ServiceOperations.java:52)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stopQuietly(ServiceOperations.java:80)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:171)
    at  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.initAndStartNodeManager(NodeManager.java:338)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.main(NodeManager.java:386)
   2015-05-29 15:06:00,960 FATAL   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager: Error starting NodeManager
     org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: Failed to initialize container executor
    at   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.serviceInit(NodeManager.java:148)
    at    org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
    at   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.initAndStartNodeManager(NodeManager.java:338)
    at    org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.main(NodeManager.java:386)
   Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/home/hadoopnew/hadoop-2.2.0/bin/container-executor": error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1041)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:407)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:379)
    at   org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:589)
    at    org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.LinuxContainerExecutor.init(LinuxContainerExecutor.java:147)
    at    org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.serviceInit(NodeManager.java:146)
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:135)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1022)
    ... 8 more
   2015-05-29 15:06:00,976 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
```

How to resolve this error and what exactly it missing ?

Comment: Did you set JSVC Home in your hadoop packages? http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SecureMode.html#Secure_DataNode

Comment: Dinesh can you pls look to my updated question